# Dynamically autofill cells VBA if value on the left side

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how can I create a VBA code that autofills a cell if cells left side of it have any value. I have tried by (xlDown)) but it crashes the my Excel - workbook. Because my data changes weekly I would need a dynamical solution. Simple example below where I would like to have value 100 into all the cells in column3.

╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Column1 ║ Column2 ║ Column3 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ ABC     ║ AK      ║ 100     ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ ABC     ║         ║         ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ ABC     ║ AK      ║         ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, either VBA

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To Rows.Count
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Or Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
    Cells(i, 3).Value = "100"
End If
Next i
```

or as cell function

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK(A2));(NOT(ISBLANK(B2))));100;0)
```

Comment: Thank you the solutions works. But I have an other issue now. If I have previously filtered the row 2(example). Now it seems that it doesn't take into account the filtering at all and just inserts that "100" to all of the cells in column 3.

Comment: Do you have an example? Maybe screenshots?